# Retrieve Unprocessed items from BatchWriteItemRequest

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have got an operation that inserts items to dynamodb in batch. I have seen plenty of posts where people handle unprocessed items by making subsequent requests. In my scenario I want something a bit different. I want to be able to extract the **Items** from the unprocessedItems list to then log them into Kibana.

```
List<List<Item>> batchItems = Lists.partition(items, 25);

    var promises = batchItems.stream().map(itemsList -> Blocking.get(() -> {
        TableWriteItems tableWriteItems = new TableWriteItems(table.getTableName());
        tableWriteItems.withItemsToPut(itemsList);
        BatchWriteItemOutcome outcome = dynamoDB.batchWriteItem(tableWriteItems);
        final int status = outcome.getBatchWriteItemResult().getSdkHttpMetadata().getHttpStatusCode();
        return outcome.getUnprocessedItems().values();
    })).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That is the current logic I have, to sum up, I will have an array of promises that may or may not have unprocessed items.

```
ParallelPromises.yieldAll(promises).map((List<? extends ExecResult<Collection<List<WriteRequest>>>> results) -> {
//from results I want to extract the Item/Items
//that failed but currently I only have the WriteRequest that failed. Can I convert it to an Item somehow?
}
```

My core question is in the comment of the block of code above, thank you